# How do I parse an image sent from Retrofit API from Android (multipart/form) in Python's Flask

Tags: javascript, java, rest, flask, retrofit

I am sending my image as a part of Form Data through Retrofit API. There are no issues loading the image. I am trying to get this image in a Python Flask server.

My python code is not responding the expected way. I have tested my Python code with a JavaScript frontend application and the python server responds as expected. I believe the issue is parsing the multipart/form file which I receive from Android.

There are no network issues, I am able to log the requests. The **detectFace()** function is not responding as expected for the same image sent through both clients, VueJs and Android.
Any ideas will be appreciated.

**Here is the android code for uploading:**

```
private void sendImageToServer() {
        File imageFile = loadImageFromStorage(tempImagePath);
        RequestBody reqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), imageFile);
        MultipartBody.Part partImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", "testImage", reqBody);
        API api = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getAPI();
        Call<TestResult> upload = api.uploadImage(partImage);
        upload.enqueue(new Callback<TestResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<TestResult> call, Response<TestResult> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    TestResult res = response.body();
                    String jsonRes = new Gson().toJson(response.body());
                    String result = res.getResult();
                    Log.v("REST22", result);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<TestResult> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v("REST22", t.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Here is Python code:**

```
@app.route('/detectFaces/', methods=['POST'])
def detectFaces():
    img = request.files.get('file')
    print('LOG', request.files)
    groupName = 'random-group-03'
    result = face.detectFaces(img, groupName)
    print('RESULT', result)
    return {'result' : result[0]}
```

**VueJs - alternate working frontend (REST client):**

```
sendImage(img) {
      console.log(img)
      var form = new FormData();
      form.append('file', img, 'testImage')
      axios.post(this.baseUrl + 'detectFaces/?groupName=random-group-03', form)
      .then(res => {console.log(res.data); this.log = 'Detected face ids: \n ' + res.data.result});
    }
```